# Add Custom ComboBox Filters to Admin User List in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, list, filter

I want to add 2 combo box in Admin User List Panel. For example the first one will be a combo box with countries and the other combo will be User Age. 
So I want to add these combos in order to filter the user list.

Could you please shed some light here?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i'm looking for:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'my_restrict_manage_posts');
function my_restrict_manage_posts()
{
  global $typenow;

  if ($typenow == 'your_custom_post_type') {
    $args = array(
      'show_option_all' => "Show All Categories",
      'taxonomy' => 'your_custom_taxonomy',
      'name' => 'your_custom_taxonomy'

    );
    wp_dropdown_categories($args);
  }
}

add_action('request', 'my_request');    
function my_request($request)
{
  if (is_admin() && $GLOBALS['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/edit.php' && isset($request['post_type']) && $request['post_type'] == 'your_custom_post_type') {
    $request['term'] = get_term($request['your_custom_taxonomy'], 'your_custom_taxonomy')->name;
  }
  return $request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own fields to a user add/edit field.
this example shows how to add a address input field, if you get this working try switching it with the dropdown's that you need. If that's what you mean by 'combobox'

```
function fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
    <h3><?php _e('Extra Profile Information', 'your_textdomain'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
    <th>
    <label for="address"><?php _e('Address', 'your_textdomain'); ?>
    </label></th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'address', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
    <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter your address.', 'your_textdomain'); ?></span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php }
    function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return FALSE;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
    }
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```